# Defining a function that returns an (interpolated) function

Tags: python, interpolation, currying

I'm trying to write a function that returns an interpolating function that linearly extrapolates outside of the interpolating range. After looking at the posts on currying, I can't figure out why what I have doesn't work. I have:

```
def interpolation(X_list,a_list): 
    A1=scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(
        np.asarray(X_list),
        np.asarray(a_list),
        k=3,
        s=0,
        check_finite=True)

    m=(((a_list[-1])-(a_list[-2]))
       / ((X_list[-1])-(X_list[-2])))

    A1ext= m*X+a_list[-1]-m*X_list[-1]

    def a(X):
        if X_list[-1]>=X:
            return A1
        if X>X_list[-1]:
            return A1ext
    return a(X)
```

Comment: Wow, this is so hard to read.

Comment: Don't you just want to return `A1`?

Comment: Using `len()` in the indices is unnecessary. `a_list[len(a_list)-1]` can be written as just `a_list[-1]`. That will go some way toward making the code more readable.

Comment: No - sadly the univariate spline is not a good approximation outside the interpolation range

Comment: Just return `a`

Answer (score 1):

Just return the inner function

```
def interpolation(X_list,a_list): 
    A1=scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(
        np.asarray(X_list),
        np.asarray(a_list),
        k=3,
        s=0,
        check_finite=True)

    m=(((a_list[-1])-(a_list[-2]))
       / ((X_list[-1])-(X_list[-2])))

    A1ext= m*X+a_list[-1]-m*X_list[-1]

    def a(X):
        if X_list[-1]>=X:
            return A1
        if X>X_list[-1]:
            return A1ext
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = interpolation(X_list,a_list)
    a(X)
```

To make it shorter, you can replace that inner function (`a`) with a lambda anonymous function:

```
lambda X: A1 if X_list[-1] >= X else A1ext
```

So it will now be:

```
def interpolation(X_list,a_list): 
    A1=scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline(
        np.asarray(X_list),
        np.asarray(a_list),
        k=3,
        s=0,
        check_finite=True)

    m=(((a_list[-1])-(a_list[-2]))
       / ((X_list[-1])-(X_list[-2])))

    A1ext= m*X+a_list[-1]-m*X_list[-1]

    return lambda X: A1 if X_list[-1] >= X else A1ext
```

Comment: Thanks for the code smac! When I tried to run this, I get an error on the A1ext line because X is not defined?

Comment: @лаетековскийчайник if you are talking about the first one, then just remember that the lines below `__main__` are just filler code. You need to define those parameters somewhere before calling the functions

Comment: I tried it with the second one, let me try it with the first one too